# Redirecting stdout to multiple output widgets

Tags: csv, python-3.x, tkinter, stdout

I have program that searches a CSV file, and outputs the entire row to a single output widget via stdout text direction. What I would like is to split some fields from this row so that one field goes to one output widget, another goes to another widget etc. I presume its through some loop technique but not exactly sure what to do.

The code for the search CSV, redirection to the single output widget follows if this helps.

```
#output
    self.label4 = ttk.Label(rootWindow, text="Drawings:")
    self.label4.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=(N,E), padx=3, pady=3)

    self.dwgoutputbox = Text(rootWindow, width=50, height=15, background="white", font="system_font 10")
    self.dwgoutputbox.grid(row=3, column=2, columnspan=5, padx=3, pady=3)
    sys.stdout = TextRedirector(self.dwgoutputbox, "printdwgoutputbox") 

    #buttons
    def DoASearch():
        self.outputQty.delete(1.0, 'end')
        self.outputDesc.delete(1.0, 'end')
        self.dwgoutputbox.configure(state="normal")
        self.dwgoutputbox.delete(1.0, 'end')
        self.dwgoutputbox.configure(state="disabled")
        try:
            (int(sonumber.get()))
            checkcsv()
        except ValueError:
            messagebox.showwarning("Fail !!", "Please enter a valid Shop Order number.")

    def checkcsv():
        with open("spreadsheettest.csv") as csvfile:
            reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
            for row in reader:
                result=(row['Shop Order'])
                if sonumber.get() == result:
                    descQty=(row['Quantity'])
                    descInfo=(row['Description'])
                    descPN=(row['Part Number'])
                    descDwg=(row['Drawings'])

    self.searchbutton = ttk.Button(rootWindow, text="Search", command=DoASearch)
    self.searchbutton.grid(row=1, column=7, sticky=W, padx=3, pady=3)


    def clear_text():
        self.SOentry.delete(0, 'end')
        self.outputQty.delete(1.0, 'end')
        self.outputDesc.delete(1.0, 'end')
        self.dwgoutputbox.configure(state="normal")
        self.dwgoutputbox.delete(1.0, 'end')
        self.dwgoutputbox.configure(state="disabled")

    self.clrsearchbutton = ttk.Button(rootWindow, text="Reset", command=clear_text)
    self.clrsearchbutton.grid(row=2, column=7, sticky=W, padx=3, pady=3)

    self.exitbutton = ttk.Button(rootWindow, text="Exit", command=rootWindow.destroy)
    self.exitbutton.grid(row=3, column=7, sticky=(N,W), padx=3, pady=3)


class TextRedirector(object):
def __init__(self, widget, tag="printdwgoutputbox"):
    self.widget = widget
    self.tag = tag

def write(self, str):
    self.widget.configure(state="normal")
    self.widget.insert("end", str, (self.tag,))
    self.widget.configure(state="disabled")
```

I've modified the code as suggested below and it all seems to work nicely and updates as I change data in the input text widget

```
        def checkcsv():
        with open("lesspreadsheettest.csv") as csvfile:
            reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
            for row in reader:
                result=(row['Shop Order'])
                if sonumber.get() == result:
                    descQty=(row['Quantity'])
                    descInfo=(row['Description'])
                    descPN=(row['Part Number'])
                    descDwg=(row['Drawings'])
                    self.outputQty.insert(INSERT,descQty)
                    self.outputDesc.insert(INSERT,descPN)
                    self.outputDesc.insert(INSERT,descInfo)
                    self.dwgoutputbox.insert(INSERT,descDwg)

    self.searchbutton = ttk.Button(rootWindow, text="Search", command=DoASearch)
    self.searchbutton.grid(row=1, column=7, sticky=W, padx=3, pady=3)
```

Comment: Where is your `write(str)` function being called? And what string is being passed to it? Once you figure that out, you can simply repeat that for the other portion of the text.

Comment: @jdep I've included where the write(str) is called from, I've also allocated stringvars for the columns in each target rows of the CSV, however I'm not sure of the steps to repeatly call the text redirection object so that I can send these variables to the appropriate text output widgets

Comment: I think your idea of "redirecting stdout to multiple widgets" is leading you astray. Redirecting `stdout` is only really useful if you're using things like `print` in your code and want it to appear in your GUI. If you want to update other UI widgets, just use regular tkinter code, like you're doing elsewhere. It doesn't make any sense to try to tie other output streams into the `stdout` file.

Comment: @Blckknght thats something I didnt even consider, I was making things more difficult for myself than they need be. Thank you. I've modified the code above